# Replacing a 15A outlet with a 5A outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

I currently have a 15A outlet, which I am trying to replace with a 5A outlet (without changing the wiring) so that I can use it to plug in my refrigerator. 
Is it OK to do so?
Can it harm the appliances that are connected to the outlet?

Ps - we have 220v/50Hz

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: You should mention specific country or region.

Comment: You'd be better changing the plug on the fridge to a 15A. I'm guessing a commonwealth country using the old British 3 round pin plugs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're intent on replacing the outlet rather than the refrigerator's plug, and want it to be safe, you can replace the 15A outlet with a box that has a 5A circuit breaker feeding a 5A outlet.

You can also keep the 15A outlet and have the above mentioned box as an adapter that connects to the 15A outlet with a 15A plug.

Answer (score 0):

The outlet, if it is rated a 5A, do not use it. They are rated for a purpose. 
It may not damage the appliance but the receptacle itself may fail, and no way to determine how that will occur, either by just not working, or working no more by fire.